# WSO2 Disable HTTPS and SSL

Tags: http, ssl, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to access to wso2 api manager with http://myIP:9763/publisher but it's redirected to https://myIP:9443/publisher.

I have done this:
Go to the $WSO2_HOME/repository/conf and open carbon.xml, and uncomment

<EnableHTTPAdminConsole>true</EnableHTTPAdminConsole>
Disable secure cookie parameter in $WSO2_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml file as well.

in session-config changed secury to false

also I have done this:
change redirectPort = "9443" to "-1"

but after starting wso2 the all the configs changes back to their default.
I am using WSO2 API manager 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these parameters have not been properly templated by the product, you  might have to modify the `xml.j2` directly instead of the `xml` file.

You can find those files in following locations

`repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/carbon.xml.j2`

`repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml.j2`

The xml files will be overridden with the values in j2 files in runtime.

Comment: Thanks but it's also redirects to https.
Is there any way to fix it ?